# How to use JUCE for generating wav file using MIDI file and soundfonts file?

Tags: android, midi, juce, soundfont

For last few days I have been trying to generate a wav file using `MIDI` and `soundfont` file in an **android app**. For that I have tried building [fluidsynth](https://github.com/VolcanoMobile/fluidsynth-android/) for this purpose. I have been able to build it successfully but the problem is that fast-rendering does not seem to be supported in this build. Now, I am looking at other alternatives for a similar purpose.

I came across JUCE as an another option for playing with MIDI and soundfonts. Anyone having idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I use [FluidLite](https://github.com/divideconcept/FluidLite) and JUCE together to play soundfonts. Its very simple & cross platform!

Here is a working demo:

https://github.com/cpenny42/juce-soundfonts

I've used this in a variety of apps, all of which run on Android (as well as iOS, Mac, Windows, Linux).